# вызывался ли метод за timeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c

Я новичок в iOS разработке, возник у меня вопрос относительно таймеров. Предположим есть некий timer который считает до nSeс после чего уничтожается, и метод testMetod. Как можно определить, вызывался ли testMetod в период жизни таймера?

Answer (score 0):

В `testMetod` напишите:

```
NSLog(@"Hello I am testMetod")
```

Comment: мне необходимо узнать выполнится он или нет именно за этот промежуток времени. Если выполняется я программа выполнит метод 1, если нет то метод 2.

Comment: @Hudihka Сделайте еще один таймер, который будет проверять изменилась ли переменная-флаг. Если нет, то выполнит метод 2.

Answer (score 0):

Вы говорите, таймер уничтожается после завершения. Тогда можно сделать так: предположим, ваш метод называется testMethod, и область видимости таймера позволяет увидеть его из тела метода.

```
- (void)testMethod
{
  if (timer) {
    // Зовёте метод 1
  } else {
    // Зовёте метод 2
  }
  // Код самого testMethod
}
```